# li:after auto size & :after on a :after element?

Tags: css

I have some CSS questions.

1. I have a `li` element with a certain width. I also want a `:after`
   element for this `li` and use this as a tooltip. Is it possible to
   give the tooltip an auto width and center it above the `li`?
2. If I have the tooltip in the `li:after` element working I still need a
   little triangle arrow for it therefor I would need to apply a `:after`
   element on a `:after` element. Is this possible?

Comment: The answer to #2 is no. You should be able to use both `:before` and `:after` to achieve the same thing though.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is triangle, followed by tooltip text, you can achieve this by using :before and :after (as suggested in the comment). The below example, also available on dabblet, should give you an idea.
 http://dabblet.com/gist/4280779

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li>first - no tooltip</li>
 <li data-tooltip="Tooltip second">Second</li>
 <li data-tooltip="Tooltip third">third</li>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  color: #900;
}

li:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

li[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 20px;
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: -150%;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  z-index: 20;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #333;  
  background-color: black; 
 }

 li[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
  content: "\0394";
  padding-left: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px; 
  top: -150%;
  color: yellow;
  z-index: 21;  
 }
```

You can make the tooltip look nice by replacing background-color with background-image / gradient, etc.